# "Circulant" matrices of arbitrary step size, do they also have special basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, diagonalization, canonical-transformation, circulant-matrices

Circulant matrices are famous because they are diagonalized by vectors being the basis functions to the Discrete Fourier Transform.

But what happens if we slightly modify a circulant matrix, so that there is a "gap" of $2$ instead of $1$ for each new row? Let us only consider odd sized matrices as AndreasH pointed out degeneracy of even sized ones below.

For example like this:
$$D = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0&0&0&0\\
     0&     0&     1&    -1&     0&     0&0\\
     0&     0&     0&     0&     1&    -1&0\\
     -1&     0&    0&     0&     0&     0&1\\
     0&     1&    -1&     0&    0&     0&0\\
     0&     0&     0&     1&     -1&     0&0\\
     0&     0&     0&     0&     0&     1&-1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can we derive as a function of say the first row what the eigenbasis shall look like in a general case?

Comment: @mathreader I think your example is incorrectly constructed. I think row 4,5,6 should actually be the same as row 1,2,3.

Comment: Given this observation, I think it makes a difference if the shift and the dimension of the matrix are coprime or not. In the first case the matrix is just a row permutation of the shift-1 circulant matrix. In the other case the matrix contains duplicate rows (and is for instance singular)

Comment: @AndreasH. You are correct it is incorrectly constructed. Row 4 should be row 2, which makes it kind of uninteresting as it will be trivially degenerate. I will fix it by considering odd sized matrices only.